# Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[/etc/awslogs//cwlogs.cfg]'

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, packer

I am trying to do a chef run but keep receiving the error in the title. The log output is as follows;

```
Project: Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[/etc/awslogs//cwlogs.cfg]'
Project: ================================================================================
Project:
Project: Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError
Project: ------------------------------------
Project: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
Project:
Project: Resource Declaration:
Project: ---------------------
Project: # In /tmp/packer-chef-solo/cookbooks-0/cloudwatch-cookbook/recipes/logconfig.rb
Project:
Project: 21: template "#{node['cloudwatch-cookbook']['cwlogs']['directory']}/#{node['cloudwatch-cookbook']['cwlogs']['configfilename']}" do
Project: 22:    source   "cwlogs.cfg.erb"
Project: 23:    owner    "root"
Project: 24:    group    "root"
Project: 25:    mode     0644
Project: 26:    variables(
Project: 27:        :cookbook_name => "cloudwatch-cookbook"
Project: 28:   )
Project: 29: end
Project:
Project: Compiled Resource:
Project: ------------------
Project: # Declared in /tmp/packer-chef-solo/cookbooks-0/cloudwatch-cookbook/recipes/logconfig.rb:21:in `from_file'
Project:
Project: template("/etc/awslogs//cwlogs.cfg") do
Project: action "create"
Project: retries 0
Project: retry_delay 2
Project: default_guard_interpreter :default
Project: path "/etc/awslogs//cwlogs.cfg"
Project: backup 5
Project: atomic_update true
Project: source "cwlogs.cfg.erb"
Project: variables {:cookbook_name=>"cloudwatch-cookbook"}
Project: declared_type :template
Project: cookbook_name :"cloudwatch-cookbook"
Project: recipe_name "logconfig"
Project: mode 420
Project: owner "root"
Project: group "root"
Project: end
Project:
Project: Template Context:
Project: -----------------
Project: on line #31
Project: 29: <% node['cloudwatch-cookbook']['cwlogs']['logfiles'].each do |group| -%>
Project: 30:
Project: 31: [<%= group['groupname'] %>_<%= group['logfile'] %>]
Project: 32: datetime_format = [%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]
Project: 33: log_group_name = <%= group['groupname'].gsub(' ', '_') %>
Project:
Project: Recipe: apache2::default
Project: * service[apache2] action reload
Project: - reload service service[apache2]
Project:
Project: Running handlers:
Project: [2015-05-11T11:03:15+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Project: Running handlers complete
Project: [2015-05-11T11:03:15+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Project: [2015-05-11T11:03:15+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Project: Chef Client failed. 99 resources updated in 301.919689764 seconds
Project: [2015-05-11T11:03:15+00:00] ERROR:
Project:
Project: Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer) on line #31:
Project:
Project: 29: <% node['cloudwatch-cookbook']['cwlogs']['logfiles'].each do |group| -%>
Project: 30:
Project: 31: [<%= group['groupname'] %>_<%= group['logfile'] %>]
Project: 32: datetime_format = [%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]
Project: 33: log_group_name = <%= group['groupname'].gsub(' ', '_') %>
Project:
Project: (erubis):31:in `[]'
Project: (erubis):31:in `block (2 levels) in evaluate'
Project: (erubis):29:in `each'
Project: (erubis):29:in `block in evaluate'
```

I have tried looking over the existing answers to similar questions but they've all identified different problems that don't seem to reflect what is happening in my case.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How are defined `node['cloudwatch-cookbook']['cwlogs']['logfiles']` attributes? Can you post some examples? It seems you are accessing them as node['cloudwatch-cookbook']['cwlogs']['logfiles'] were a hashmap but it is an array.

Comment: The logfiles are defined thus;  `'logfile'    => '@CW_LOG_FILE@',
  'groupname'  => '@CW_GROUP_NAME@',
  'streamname' => '{instance_id}'` and the attributes are passed through a json file as `"cloudwatch-cookbook" : {
                  "cwlogs" : {
                      "logfiles" : {
                          "logfile" : "/var/log/syslog",
                          "groupname" : "Project",
                          "streamname" : "Project"
                          },
                      "region" : "eu-west-1"
                  }
              }`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.each` on a has will return `|key, value|`.  You are only grabbing the `key` which is a string.  You then call `string['something']` which expects an index on the string.

If you change line 29 to read:

```
<% node['cloudwatch-cookbook']['cwlogs']['logfiles'].values do |group| -%>
```

you should be good to go.